# Calling a function in an extension from another extension

Tags: ckan

I'm new to ckan & python so thank you for any feedback.

I have this route set up in a CKAN extension (ie: **exporter**):

```py
def after_map(self, m):
  m.connect('export', Export.route_path, controller='ckanext.export.plugin:ExportController', action='generate_export')
```

How would I call that route from another extension (ie: **importer**)?

Does CKAN have something like this?

```py
helper.call_route(controller='ckanext.export.plugin:ExportController', action='generate_export')
# OR
helper.call_named('export')
```

that I can call from inside the **importer** extension to access that **generate_export** method?

or maybe get a list of actions that are available in another CKAN extension and call the 'generate_export' method?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already consider trying the `get_action` function, that is provided by the plugin toolbox?

it's described [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugins-toolkit.html#ckan.plugins.toolkit.ckan.plugins.toolkit.get_action) :)